# How do I display the "Reply" button next to a message sent from a Kik bot?

Tags: bots, kik

Like this ( the reply button next to the second response)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your messages suggested responses through the keyboard property
https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#keyboards

Ensure you have the chatId set as well on the messages you are sending.
Then if you mention the bot you are working on @your_bot_username hi if the response has suggested responses the reply button will show up